# T-SQL: stored procedure to increment products views count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I am a very beginner with sql and I need to write a SP in order to increment products  views count. When user searches on site we want to increment the counter for all products that were returned by search. I see two problems with my SP:

1. it uses cursor
2. it starts a lot of transactions

The SP is called simultaneous by many threads. After I implemented it I got many timeout exceptions. My count table looks like this:

ProductsViewsCount(ProductId int, Timestamp datetime, ViewType int, Count int)

Tiemstamp column is rounded to the closest hour in .net code that calls the SP. Basically I will count the views by hour.

The SP looks like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IncrementProductsViews]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProductsIds as varchar(max) = '', --CSV ids of products that were returned by search
    @ViewType int,
    @Timestamp datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @id int 
    DECLARE idsCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Data FROM dbo.Split(@ProductsIds,',')

    OPEN idsCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM idsCursor INTO @id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE dbo.ProductsViewsCount SET Count = Count + 1 
                WHERE ProductId = @id AND ViewType = @ViewType AND Timestamp = @Timestamp
            if @@rowcount = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.ProductsViewsCount (ProductId, Timestamp, ViewType, Count) 
                    VALUES (@id, @Timestamp, @ViewType, 1)
            END
        COMMIT TRAN     
        FETCH NEXT FROM idsCursor INTO @id
    END     
    CLOSE idsCursor   
    DEALLOCATE idsCursor
    select 1
END
```

Can I do this in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it on a set operation instead of a cursor:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IncrementProductsViews]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProductsIds as varchar(max) = '', --CSV ids of products that were returned by search
    @ViewType int,
    @Timestamp datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.ProductsViewsCount
        WHERE ViewType = @ViewType AND [Timestamp] = @Timestamp
    )


    MERGE CTE AS A
    USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@ProductsIds,',')) B
    ON A.ProductId = B.Data 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.[Count] = B.[Count] + 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(ProductId, [Timestamp], ViewType, [Count])
    VALUES(Data, @Timestamp, @ViewType, 1);

    SELECT 1 -- I don't know why this is here
END
```

Comment: can I somehow avoid doing transactions? I mean if I can lock only the row I am updating? I assume that transactions are the most expensive operations.

Comment: @RaduD - Ok, I changed my query so it uses the `MERGE` statement, wrapping the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` on the same command. This way, you can do it without a transaction with less risk than both statements separated.

Comment: one more beginner question ;) Will the CTE be evaluated at the moment when merge is evaluated? If the SP is called from multiple threads could if be a gap till the CTE is evaluated and when the merge is evaluates?

Comment: I satill have 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object' exceptions. It means that MERGE cannot deal properly with the race condition

Comment: @RaduD You never mentioned that you had a *Cannot insert duplicate key in object*, that means that you are not taking duplicates into account

Comment: I fixed the problem with a lock: '... merge CTE WITH (HOLDLOCK) as A
    using (select * from dbo.Split ...' and now I had no exceptions today. It seems working fine. But to be honest I don't really understand what that lock does ;)

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 2008 you have a nice new option (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(SQL.100).aspx):

```
with ProductViewsCountSelect as (select * from ProductViewsCount where ViewType = @ViewType and [Timestamp] = @Timestamp)
merge into ProductViewsCountSelect
    using (select data, count(*) as cnt from dbo.split('A,B,C,A', ',') group by data) d on ProductViewsCountSelect.ProductId = d.data
    when matched   
        then update set ProductViewsCountSelect.Count = ProductViewsCountSelect.count + cnt
    when not matched 
         then insert (ProductId, [TimeStamp], ViewType, [Count]) values( d.data, @TimeStamp, @ViewType, cnt);
```

Comment: I had actually updated my answer so it uses `MERGE` instead of `UPDATE` and `INSERT` a while ago

Comment: I have no idea why this script insert only the first time. When the viewtype is changed I get no inserts at all.

Comment: That's right. Because my answert above is wrong :-/
If you have a already an entry for the ViewType, then there is a match on ProductId. So you are in the when match part. If this is not true because of the ViewType part, the when not matched part is not executed. That's why in your accepted answer a CTE is used.

Comment: there is a problem also with the accepted answer ... it gives 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object' ... basically there is a race condition and the MERGE command seems not to deal properly with that.

Comment: I see, you have more than once the same productid in your input string. That's indeed a problem with the cte.

Comment: Was that the reason? I modified my answer to work with duplicate productids in the string. Does it help?